# NodeJs requests callbacks in Dart

Tags: node.js, dart

I'm trying to convert the following Node.js snippet to Dart. In my conversion the 'data returned...' message is printed as soon as there is a response unlike in the Node.js version which waits until the page completes the requested 2 second delay.

Node.js

```
var http = require('http')    
function fetchPage() {
  console.log('fetching page');
  http.get({ host: 'trafficjamapp.herokuapp.com', path: '/?delay=2000' }, function(res) {
    console.log('data returned from requesting page');
  }).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("There was an error" + e);
  });
}
```

Dart

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:uri';

fetchPage() {
  print('fetching page');
  var client = new HttpClient();
  var uri = new Uri.fromComponents(scheme:'http', domain: 'trafficjamapp.herokuapp.com', path: '?delay=2000');
  var connection = client.getUrl(uri);

  connection.onRequest = (HttpClientRequest req) {
    req.outputStream.close();
  };

  connection.onResponse = (HttpClientResponse res){
    print('data returned from requesting page');
  };

  connection.onError = (e) => print('There was an error' ' $e');
}
```

How do I achieve the same delayed print in Dart as in Node? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Dart code was almost right, but there was a bug. You should have used `query` named parameter instead of `path`. I don't really know which Url is call with your code but the response has a `400` status code. For more readability, you can also use the `Uri.fromString` constructor.

Moreover you can omit your `onRequest` setting because the same code is done when `onRequest` is not defined.

Here's the code :

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:uri';

main() {
  print('fetching page');
  //var uri = new Uri.fromString('http://trafficjamapp.herokuapp.com/?delay=2000');
  var uri = new Uri.fromComponents(scheme:'http',
      domain: 'trafficjamapp.herokuapp.com', query: 'delay=2000');
  var client = new HttpClient();
  var connection = client.getUrl(uri);
  connection.onResponse = (HttpClientResponse res){
    print('data returned from requesting page with status ${res.statusCode}');
  };
  connection.onError = (e) => print('There was an error' ' $e');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I see now that I could have added the '/' in front of the path named parameter to make my code work as well but using the query name parameter makes the intention much clearer.

Comment: Will this Dart code scale like Node.js will?  Under the hood does it use Asynchronous I/O?

Answer (score 1):

You can find this in the documentation of the `onResponse` callback:

> The callback is called when all headers of the response are received and data is ready to be received.

So it works like this:

```
connection.onResponse = (res) {
  print('Headers received, can read the body now');
  var in = res.inputStream;

  in.onData = () {
    // this can be called multiple times
    print('Received data');
    var data = in.read();
    // do something with data, probably?
  };
  in.onClosed = () {
    // this is probably the event you are interested in
    print('No more data available');
  };
  in.onError = (e) {
    print('Error reading data: $e');
  };
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this as well. I now see how to consume the stream and get the closed event. I just had to rename the 'in' variable and had to add the '/' to the beginning of my original path.